# unrecognized or unsupported array type exception in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image conversion in OpenCV C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149510/image-conversion-in-opencv-c)

`WeightedImg.Bitmap.SetPixel(x, y,Color.FromArgb((int)Math.Ceiling(color * R),
   (int)Math.Ceiling(color * G),(int)Math.Ceiling(color * B)));`

this line of code produces the exception above .. any one knows the solution ?
and what does the exception mean?
thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please post the exception as well?

Comment: your problem is probably in the part you haven't included in your question, where you assign the result of the expression to a variable. Try checking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579332/an-exception-on-opencv-matrix-function)

Comment: try splitting that line up into more lines using more variables and debug to see if anything peculiar shows up there

Comment: the exception in the title .. unrecognized or unsupported array type

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the alphachannel, as in **A**rgb
The alphachannel set's the transparency of the color

Comment: no, that is not the problem .. :)

Answer (score 0):

you really need to give us more to work on. how are those variables defined? what's the exception and stack trace print? this equivalent of what you're posting, for example, works as a charm on my machine

```
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap("somefile.bmp");
        double color = 1, R = 2, G = 3, B = 4;
        int x = 1, y = 1;
        b.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb((int)Math.Ceiling(color * R), (int)Math.Ceiling(color * G), (int)Math.Ceiling(color * B)));
```